# accept() and connect() methods in bluetooth socket

Tags: android, sockets, android-bluetooth

I am getting bluetooth socket connection problem and so tried various alternatives to connect.

It is like if first fails then second and if second also fails then third and so the main UI blocks during the process.

The exceptions are like -

`"Service discovery failed"` OR `"Host is down"`

My all three alternatives -

**1)** **Connect with a connect() function**

```
   m = bdDevice.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[] {int.class});

   socket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(bdDevice, Integer.valueOf(i));

   mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

   socket.connect();
```

**2) Connect with a accept() function**

```
   m = bdDevice.getClass().getMethod ("listenUsingRfcommOn", new Class [] {int.class}); 

   BluetoothServerSocket returnValue = 
   (BluetoothServerSocket) m.invoke(bdDevice, new Object [] {29});

   socket = returnValue.accept();
```

**3) Connect with a well know SPP UUID**

```
 private final UUID my_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

 socket = bdDevice.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(my_UUID);

 mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

 socket.connect();
```

The second alternative is recently added and so I am not sure that how is it different from first and third one. All will block the UI until connect, all can through IOException.

Comment: You just need to understand that `connect()` is for clients and `accept()` is for servers. Why all the reflection?

Comment: I am using all the alternatives- first and second as reflection and third is without reflection. I am using all because I am unable to connect to the remote SPP blackbox device. So if first alternative fails then it will try with another like that.

Comment: I want to send data in bytes (RUN Command) to blackbox device (SPP) after a socket connection. The command will trigger blackbox to send broadcast messages to my android device. So its like two way communication. So should I use connect() or accept() ?

Comment: Reflection doesn't solve network problems, or design problems, or not knowing what code to write. You should use `connect()` if you're a client and `accept()` if you're a server. I already said that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** You are connecting as a client to your SPP device. Therefore your device must be expecting a connection before you can actually connect.

**2)** You are accepting the connection as the server. Your bluetooth device will be responsible for firing the connection requests.

**3)** You are connecting to a device that uses a particular UUID as it's Serial Port Profile (SPP). Think of this as similar to ports in http protocol. The 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB, is one of the most common ones. More info : https://developer.bluetooth.org/TechnologyOverview/Pages/SPP.aspx

**Additionally**, if you are thinking on supporting multiple OS / handset versions. You might see those error messages after an initial broken comm. Android's bluetooth stack (bluez) was totally replaced on 4.2, but you might need to still handle previous known bugs.

Reflection in this case is a good thing (some parts of the bluetooth API wasn't public in older versions). But, in my experience, API level < 17; using **createInsecureRfcommSocket** instead of **createRfcommSocket** is much more reliable.

Hope this helps. But if you are building an app for a custom bluetooth spp device of yours, explaining how that devices handles comms could help pointing out the exact root of your problem. Although, bluetooth on Android is never straight forward.

Comment: Can I use `createInsecureRfcommSocket ` for API level > 17 as well ? My devices are already paired when I initiate connection so my "insecure" socket approach is fine ?

Comment: @VedPrakash; Yes you can. Insecure basically means that the user won't be involved in the authentication process and the communication channel will not have an authenticated link key i.e it will be subject to man-in-the-middle attack(described in docs). I usually use secure comms as a rule, but due to legacy bluetooth bugs (mostly in 4.0, 4.1 Android's bluetooth stack), insecure works best. But, if for you secure comms is not a must, then insecure is just fine.

Comment: I want to send data in bytes (RUN Command) to blackbox device (SPP) after a socket connection. The command will trigger blackbox to send broadcast messages to my android device. So its like two way communication. So should I use connect() or accept() ?

Comment: @VedPrakash, really depends on the spec of the device. Most devices act as a server, therefore connect(). Otherwise, accept(). But either way, you will be able to read & write data to the bluetooth radio.

Comment: ok. I have a doubt that why my universal UUID doesn't work to connect. So can I use `UUID uuid = bdDevice.getUuids()[0].getUuid();` to get the UUID ?

Comment: @VedPrakash, The UUID you're trying is the most common one. Although, might be the case that your bluetooth device uses a different UUID. You can use BluetoothDevice::getUuids(), but, i don't think this is available for API levels < 15. If this is relevant for you, consider reflection. As far as i remember, it's private API for older versions.